# Spliting the string and put value into textbox

Tags: vba, csv, textbox

I am using visual basic 2010.I have string of data in below format.I wanted to Split the comma seprated value and put into Individual text box.For The last 
**Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0**". I would like to split values alone and put into text box.

can someone suggest me how can i do it. Is there any example code.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim selectedItem1 As String
    Dim Data As String
    Private Sub SMCB1_clientIP_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_clientIP.TextChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub SMCB1_Connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_Connect.Click

        Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text
        Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text & vbNewLine & SMCB1_Port.Text & vbNewLine
        Data = "SMCB3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0"
        Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text & vbNewLine & SMCB1_Port.Text & vbNewLine & Data
        Data.Split()





    End Sub


    Private Sub SMCB1_Disconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_Disconnect.Click

    End Sub




End Class
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfOti.jpg)

> Data = "SMCB3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0"

Comment: Can you please specify the expected output you are looking for the image you have added?

Answer (score 0):

I have written code as below.There are 28 text boxes . value should get recorded into each text box. With below code i could record upto 28 value.
But From 24 the paramter contains
**Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0"**
Need to separate string ":" and put reading to particular text box.

```
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Dim selectedItem1 As String
    Dim Data As String
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim line As String

    Private Sub SMCB1_clientIP_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_clientIP.TextChanged

    End Sub


    Private Sub SMCB1_Connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_Connect.Click

        ' Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text
        'Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text & vbNewLine & SMCB1_Port.Text & vbNewLine
        Data = "SMCB3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0"
        '  Dispay_Show.Text = SMCB1_clientIP.Text & vbNewLine & SMCB1_Port.Text & vbNewLine & Data
        Dispay_Show.Text = Data

        Dim strArray() As String
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim Tempr_read As String
        Dim voltage As String
        Dim SPD As String
        Dim Dis_value As String

        Data = "SMCB3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Temp_read:348,HV_Read:647,SPD:0,DIS:0"
        strArray = Split(Data, ",")
        SMCB1_Name.Text = strArray(0)
        SMCB1_DeviceId.Text = strArray(1)
        SMCB1_String1.Text = strArray(2)
        SMCB1_String2.Text = strArray(3)
        SMCB1_String3.Text = strArray(4)
        SMCB1_String4.Text = strArray(5)
        SMCB1_String5.Text = strArray(6)
        SMCB1_String6.Text = strArray(7)
        SMCB1_String7.Text = strArray(8)
        SMCB1_String8.Text = strArray(9)
        SMCB1_String9.Text = strArray(10)

        SMCB1_String10.Text = strArray(11)
        SMCB1_String11.Text = strArray(12)
        SMCB1_String12.Text = strArray(13)
        SMCB1_String13.Text = strArray(14)
        SMCB1_String14.Text = strArray(15)
        SMCB1_String15.Text = strArray(16)
        SMCB1_String16.Text = strArray(17)
        SMCB1_String17.Text = strArray(18)
        SMCB1_String18.Text = strArray(19)
        SMCB1_String19.Text = strArray(20)

        SMCB1_String20.Text = strArray(21)
        SMCB1_String21.Text = strArray(22)
        SMCB1_String22.Text = strArray(23)
        SMCB1_String23.Text = strArray(24)
        SMCB1_String24.Text = strArray(25)

        ' Tempr_read = Split(Data(strArray(26),":")


        SMCB1_Temp.Text = strArray(26)
        SMCB1_Hvread.Text = strArray(27)
        SMCB1_SPD.Text = strArray(28)
        SMCB1_DIS.Text = strArray(29)


        For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
            Debug.Print(Trim(strArray(intCount)))
        Next
    End Sub



    Private Sub SMCB1_Disconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMCB1_Disconnect.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 2 instances of the InStrRev function - one for the colon and the other for the comma whilst looping backwards through the string and building your array.

In this way you will be able to capture the data to the right of the colon (and before the comma), yet disregard the label between the comma and the colon (if that is in fact what you intend to do).

Please hit me up if you would like a worked example.

Regards